# Roslyn Workspace Changed Event

Tags: vb.net, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

I have some code analyzers that are configurable with a menu dialog. After the user sets some options in a DialogBox, I want all my analyzers to run again since the results will be different. I know how to read the configuration information in my DialogBox from the Analyzer, and how to invoke the DialogBox passing in the Visual Studio Soluiton but I don’t know how to tell Visual Studio that it needs to rerun the analyzers. Can I raise the WorkspaceChanged event, (if so how) and will it do what I want or do I need to do something else? My code is in VB if that matters. I already have an Option menu under tools that captures the Workspace, for VB this requires hand editing the project files and replacing all "CSharp" with "VisualBasic".

Comment: `for VB this requires hand editing the project files and replacing all "CSharp" with "VisualBasic".` What do you mean? That should not be necessary.

Comment: How are you storing and reading your options?

Comment: @JasonMalinowski right now when you select the Menu Item I reinitialize them from the Solution, if one is open, then the user can unselect or Select what the want. Then I want to rerun the Analyzer with the new options. Eventually I will persist the selections somewhere in the solution, One use of this is for the NameOf Refactoring where I want to exclude offering refactoring's for symbols in Microsoft and System libraries

Comment: @SLaks I agree but it is. I have reported this on GitHub/Roslyn #5375 and it has been verified and closed (not sure why closed).

Comment: To answer your actual question, there is no public API to do this.  You could do it with a lot of Reflection, by calling http://source.roslyn.io/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Features/SolutionCrawler/SolutionCrawlerService.cs,22

Comment: I mean http://source.roslyn.io/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Features/Diagnostics/DiagnosticAnalyzerService.cs,120.  See https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/5641

Comment: @PaulCohen: if you persist them in your own little file and then include that file as an additional file, we'll reanalyze automatically when the file is changed.

Comment: @JasonMalinowski if you Reanalyze the entire solution that solves my issue. I will just persist to file in the solution somewhere.